# Do I Need an American Visa to travel to Japan from Mexico?

Tags: visas, air-travel, japan

I am Mexican and I Currently have my Mexican passport, I would like to visit Japan and I heard that if you take a flight from LAX to Japan rather than directly from Mexico it gets more affordable. My America visa is currently expired.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Yes, Mexican nationals require a visa to visit or travel through the US.  There may be flights to Japan from Mexico that don't stop in the US, but these are likely very expensive.  In my opinion a good option in searching for one of these flights might be to fly to Canada and then on to Japan - I believe Mexican Nationals don't need a visa to visit Canada